# Converting a string representing milliseconds to a Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm trying to convert a string which represents a date in a milliseconds format like this :

```
var start = new Date(s);
```

However, it seems that it does not work because when I'm trying to display the date, I've got "Invalid date" as an error message.

What I would like to get is a date in this format :

```
Wed May 07 2014 09:00:00
```

Is this possible to do?

EDIT : The original value of the s variable is a string composed of 13 number **(for instance : 13982762900000)**

Comment: Is it possible to make a live demo?

Comment: what is the content of `s` like?

Comment: Can you give an example of the `s` variable?

Comment: What is the value of  `s`?

Comment: @Traffy With jsfiddle for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert it to a numeric type instead of a string:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(s, 10))
```

**Explanation:**

The input to the `new Date()` constructor is a string. This means `new Date()` will assume the input is *"a ISO8601 string"* instead of *"Integer value representing the number of milliseconds"*, as described below.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date it should be an integer if the value shall be interpreted as *"representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch)."*

```
new Date()
```

has the following constructors (according to the link above):

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
```

**value** *(this is the constructor being used if you convert it to an integer value)*

Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).

**dateString** *(this was the constructor being called before)*

String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

Answer (score 3):

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(your_timestamp, 10));
```

A timestamp should have 13 digits.

Your example timestamp has 14 digits. Is that a mistake or the timestamp is actually wrong?

You could:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(your_timestamp, 10) / 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

Transform your string in integer with [`parseInt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) and it's working :

```
var start = new Date(parseInt(s, 10));
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2445Q/2/)

---

*Reference*

- [MDN parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
- [MDN Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: be sure to specify a radix of 10: `parseInt(s, 10)`